# Get substring through Regular Expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

```
string string1 = @"Comments by fkhan19 on Nov 01, 2018: 'ok' Comments by mzaighum on Oct 31, 2018: 'Rs.12,000,000 available in Gas is recommended for reallocation to Gen. Fuel. "
```

I have the above string and want to extract text between Comments by fkhan19 .... Comments by mzaighum

How can I do that through Regular Expression.

Comment: do you want `on Nov 01, 2018: 'ok' ` or `'ok'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either

```
[Cc]omments by [^ ]+(.+?)(?=[Cc]omments by|$)
```

or

```
[Cc]omments by [^ ]+(.+?)(?=[Cc]omments by)
```

[Demo of first pattern](https://regex101.com/r/SuNNF4/1)

[Demo of second pattern](https://regex101.com/r/SuNNF4/2)

Explanation of first pattern (second is very similair):

`[Cc]` - match `c` or `C`

`omments by` - match `omments by` literally

`[^ ]+` - match one or more of any characters other than space

`(.+?)` - match one or more of any characters (non-greedy)

`(?=[Cc]omments by|$)` - positive lookahead: assure what follows is pattern `[Cc]omments by` (explained above) or end of string `$`